# How to create a query for items that appears only in one list

Tags: sql, sqlite

The scenario I am working on is as follows:-

- A number of interviews are conducted a food poisoning case
- A query called qryFoodInCase ( `fldCaseID`, `fldFood`) is generate consisting of all the food mentioned in all the interviews
- An other query call qryFoodInInterview( `fldCaseID`, `fldInterviewID`, `fldFood`) consist of the food mentioned in each Interview

Now I am after the sql for a query that will return the food that was not consumed by an interviewee but consumed by one or more other interviewees.

The closest I've got is:

```
select Q1.fldCaseID,Q1.fldfood,Q2.fldInterviewID,fldGotSick 
from qryFoodInCases as Q1 
left join 
(select * from qryFoodInInterview where qryFoodInInterview.fldInterviewID=1) as Q2
on Q1.fldFood=Q2.fldFood 
where Q1.fldCaseID=1
```

The field Q2.fldInterviewID returns 1 for the food consumed and null for the food not consumed. However, I don't want to hard code the fldInterviewID in the sql. I would like a similar recordset returned for all the interviews in one query.

The SQL for qryFoodInCase and qryFoodInInterview are as follows:-

```
CREATE VIEW `qryFoodInCases`
AS
SELECT tblCases.fldCaseID
    ,fldfood
    ,count(tblFoodHistory.fldFoodID) AS fldFoodFrequency
FROM tblFood
INNER JOIN tblFoodHistory
    ON tblFoodHistory.fldFoodID = tblFood.fldFoodID
INNER JOIN tblMealHistory
    ON tblFoodHistory.fldMealID = tblMealHistory.fldMealHistoryID
INNER JOIN tblInterviews
    ON tblInterviews.fldInterviewID = tblMealHistory.fldInterviewID
INNER JOIN tblCases
    ON tblCases.fldCaseID = tblInterviews.fldCaseID
GROUP BY tblCases.fldCaseID, tblFood.fldFood
```

OUTPUT:

```
+-----------+------------+------------------+
| fldCaseID |  fldFood   | fldFoodFrequency |
+-----------+------------+------------------+
|         1 | Banana     |                3 |
|         1 | Beans      |                5 |
|         1 | Cabagge    |                3 |
|         1 | Chicken    |                1 |
|         1 | Pork       |                5 |
|         1 | Potatoes   |                1 |
|         1 | Rice       |                1 |
|         1 | fried fish |                1 |
|         2 | Cabagge    |                1 |
|         2 | Chicken    |                2 |
|         2 | Potatoes   |                1 |
|         2 | Rice       |                1 |
|         2 | Salad      |                1 |
+-----------+------------+------------------+
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW `qryFoodInInterview`
AS
SELECT tblInterviews.fldCaseID
    ,tblInterviews.fldInterviewID
    ,tblFood.fldFood
    ,tblInterviews.fldGotSick
FROM tblInterviews
INNER JOIN tblMealHistory
    ON tblInterviews.fldInterviewID = tblMealHistory.fldInterviewID
INNER JOIN tblFoodHistory
    ON tblFoodHistory.fldMealID = tblMealHistory.fldMealHistoryID
INNER JOIN tblFood
    ON tblFood.fldFoodID = tblFoodHistory.fldFoodID
GROUP BY tblInterviews.fldInterviewID, tblFoodHistory.fldFoodID
```

OUTPUT

```
+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
| fldCaseID | fldInterviewID |  fldFood   | fldGotSick |
+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
|         1 |              1 | Pork       |          0 |
|         1 |              1 | Banana     |          0 |
|         1 |              1 | Rice       |          0 |
|         1 |              1 | Potatoes   |          0 |
|         1 |              2 | Chicken    |          1 |
|         1 |              2 | Banana     |          1 |
|         1 |              2 | Beans      |          1 |
|         1 |              4 | Pork       |          1 |
|         1 |              4 | fried fish |          1 |
|         1 |              4 | Beans      |          1 |
|         2 |              6 | Salad      |          0 |
|         2 |              6 | Chicken    |          0 |
|         2 |              6 | Cabagge    |          0 |
|         2 |              6 | Rice       |          0 |
|         2 |              6 | Potatoes   |          0 |
|         1 |              8 | Pork       |          0 |
|         1 |              8 | Cabagge    |          0 |
|         1 |              9 | Pork       |          1 |
|         1 |              9 | Banana     |          1 |
|         1 |              9 | Beans      |          1 |
|         1 |             10 | Cabagge    |          1 |
|         1 |             10 | Beans      |          1 |
|         1 |             11 | Pork       |          1 |
|         1 |             11 | Cabagge    |          1 |
|         1 |             11 | Beans      |          1 |
+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: is `qryFoodInCase` a function or a table or a select?

Comment: qryFoodInCase and qryFoodInInterview are select queries

Comment: So your sample you are using an alias?   instead `( select ....) as qryFoodInCase`

Comment: yes I used alias just to make it easier to read

Comment: Now is better. Next time you may say. I have a `table` instead a `query`. That fact is a `view` doesnt really affect the question.

Comment: Could you include some sample data, with desire output? this is a very good tool http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: Output don't look to flash. Are there some tags that I need to add

Comment: You select the text and press `ctrl-k` to apply code format. Or add 4 space at begin of each line. You should include a tag for your rdbms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92546/discussion-between-sheils-barra-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9efc3/14)**</kbd>

- create a `cross join` off all food with all interviewrs
- then a `left join` to see which one didnt had interview
- the null mean `interview` didnt consume `food`
- and exists mean someone different to `interview` consume `food`

.

```
SELECT F.fldFood, I.fldInterviewID, FI.fldInterviewID
FROM qryFoodInCases F, (SELECT DISTINCT fldInterviewID FROM qryFoodInInterview) I
LEFT JOIN qryFoodInInterview FI
       ON F.fldFood = FI.fldFood
      AND I.fldInterviewID = FI.fldInterviewID
WHERE FI.fldInterviewID IS NULL
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM qryFoodInInterview Q1
            WHERE Q1.fldFood = F.fldFood
              AND Q1.fldInterviewID <> I.fldInterviewID)
;
```

The trick was do the thing one step at the time. Once I realize I need all the combinations and create the cross join, the rest was easy.

Comment: WOW! I have never used cross join or Exist before and the business logic of this sql is absolutely impressive

Answer (score 0):

```
select Q1.fldCaseID,Q1.fldfood,Q2.fldInterviewID,fldGotSick 
from qryFoodInCases as Q1 
left join 
(select * from qryFoodInInterview QF1
 JOIN qryFoodInInterview QF2 
 where QF1.fldInterviewID <> QF2.fldInterviewID
 AND QF1.fldInterviewID > QF2.fldInterviewID
) as Q2
on Q1.fldFood=Q2.fldFood 
where Q1.fldCaseID=1
```

As you mentioned you want to duplicate the items FoodInterviews, self JOIN will suffice your question. Please try this out , caution I didn't tested it.

Fixing Missed Self Join Condition to fix duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Juan, Will do testing

Comment: Take note of this sentence `will return the food that was not consumed by an interviewee` I solve that first creating all combinations.

Comment: Hi Shankar, This is looking promising but there seem to be a lot of duplicate.